# How to override p2 breathe theme plugin in content template file?

Tags: theme-development, templates, archives, child-theme, archive-template

I'm experimenting with a theme, P2 Breathe, the first o2-enabled theme that adds functionality like front-end posting.

One difficulty is that when the plugin is enabled, most of the changes that I make in the child theme template files just don't take unless the plugin is turned off. Is there a way to override this somehow in the template file? Unfortunately, this theme is an Automattic backburner project that does not have a support forum.

Live site: http://beertournament.com/

I did try to test with Debug This but didn't get anywhere but I can turn it on if that helps. Not sure if that poses security concern when public.

Example issue: archive-brewery.php calls content-brewery.php but none of my customizations in content-brewery.php appear live, only in the source code! Confirmed template files are what are being called via What The File.

Pastebin of archive-brewery.php & content-brewery.php: http://pastebin.com/acdtGchH